# How to appendReplacement on a Matcher group instead of the whole pattern?

Tags: java, regex, append

I am using a `while(matcher.find())` to loop through all of the matches of a Pattern.  For each instance or match of that pattern it finds, I want to replace `matcher.group(3)` with some new text.  This text will be different for each one so I am using `matcher.appendReplacement()` to rebuild the original string with the new changes as it goes through. However, `appendReplacement()` replaces the entire Pattern instead of just the group.

How can I do this but only modify the third group of the match rather than the entire Pattern?

Here is some example code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("THE (REGEX) (EXPRESSION) (WITH MULTIPLE) GROUPS");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("THE TEXT TO SEARCH AND MODIFY");
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while(matcher.find()){
   matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, processTheGroup(matcher.group(3));
}
```

but I would like to do something like this (obviously this doesn't work).

```
...
while(matcher.find()){
   matcher.group(3).appendReplacement(buffer, processTheGroup(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Something like that, where it only replaces a certain group, not the whole Pattern.

*EDIT:  changed the regex example to show that not all of the pattern is grouped.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's say your entire pattern matches `"(prefix)(infix)(suffix)"`, capturing the 3 parts into groups 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Now let's say you want to replace only group 2 (the infix), leaving the prefix and suffix intact the way they were.

Then what you do is you append what `group(1)` matched (unaltered), the new replacement for `group(2)`, and what `group(3)` matched (unaltered), so something like this:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(
    buffer,
    matcher.group(1) + processTheGroup(matcher.group(2)) + matcher.group(3)
);
```

This will still match and replace the entire pattern, but since groups 1 and 3 are left untouched, effectively only the infix is replaced.

You should be able to adapt the same basic technique for your particular scenario.

Comment: This is great thanks.  Is there also a way to do this if there are some aspects of the Pattern that are not in groups?  (I edited my original post's example)

Comment: If you must include those parts in the match (i.e. you can't leave them out of the pattern), then you'd want to capture them in a group so you can remember what they matched and put them back in unaltered as part of your replacement.

Comment: Note that this will fail if one of the matched strings contains a `$`. See Warrens answer below.

Comment: Okay, what is `processTheGroup()` ?? I want to replace lets say group 2 only

Answer (score 33):

I see this already has an accepted answer, but it is not fully correct.  The correct answer appears to be something like this:

```
.appendReplacement("$1" + process(m.group(2)) + "$3");
```

This also illustrates that "$" is a special character in .appendReplacement.  Therefore you must take care in your "process()" function to replace all "$" with "\$". Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacementString) will do this for you (thanks @Med)

The previous accepted answer will fail if either groups 1 or 3 happen to contain a "$".  You'll end up with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference"

Comment: To address this `$` issue, `Matcher.quoteReplacement( replacementString )`does the trick nicely.