# Java Replace substring in String with exact number of character

Tags: java, regex

My string is "*test*"
"test" has 4 characters
I want to replace "test" with "****"
so I get "******"

My code

```
System.out.println("_test_");
System.out.println("_test_".replaceAll("test", "*"));
```

But it replace test with 1 *.

Comment: Use `[A-Za-z]+` instead of `test` in `replaceAll().`

Comment: Of course, you specifically told it to replace `test` with a single `*`.

Comment: @noob Almost. `"_test_".replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+", "*")` will replace entire `test` with one `*`. If we want to replace each *single* character we don't need that `+`.

Comment: Will there always be delimiters of underscores between what you want to replace? For example, would `"_testing_"` be valid?

Comment: Yea I realized that later on.

Comment: @SaadA Do you want all characters to be replaced with asterisks?

Comment: @SaadA Take a look at my solution below. It can be a one liner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the answer and I was really looking for 
something with as few line as possible. Thank you all
for the answer but this is the answer I found most useful.

I apologize for not being clear in the question, if I was not.

```
String str1 = "_AnyString_";
int start_underscore = str1.indexOf("_");
int end_underscore = str1.indexOf("_", start_underscore + 1);
String str_anything = str1.substring(start_underscore + 1, end_underscore);
String str_replace_asterisk = str_anything.replaceAll(".", "*");
System.out.println(str_replace_asterisk);
str1 = str1.replace(str_anything, str_replace_asterisk);
System.out.println(str1);
```

Output:

```
_AnyString_
_*********_
```

Answer (score 3):

If the word `test` is just an example, you may use `Matcher.appendReplacement` (see [*How to appendReplacement on a Matcher group instead of the whole pattern?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940195/how-to-appendreplacement-on-a-matcher-group-instead-of-the-whole-pattern) for more details on this technique):

```
String fileText = "_test_";
String pattern = "test";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(fileText);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, repeat("*", m.group(0).length()));
}
m.appendTail(sb); // append the rest of the contents
System.out.println(sb);
```

And the `repeat` function (borrowed from [*Simple way to repeat a String in java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java), see other options there) SO post is:

```
public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    if(s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Dt2pGl)

Comment: There's also the [StringUtils.repeat](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat) that could help :-)

Comment: That is why I added the link to the SO question I borrowed the method from. I used this one for **demo only**, since I cannot use StringUtils on IDEONE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `replaceAll(str1, str2)` will replace all occurrences of `str1` with `str2`. Since you are using literals, you need to say

```
System.out.println("_test_".replaceAll("test", "****"));
```

If you want your own replacement function you can do something like this:

```
public static String replaceStringWithChar(String src, String seek, char replacement)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < seek.length(); i++) sb.append(replacement);
    return src.replaceAll(seek, sb.toString());
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
replaceStringWithChar("_test_", "test", '*');
```

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of the question, OP is really asking given a string of any arbitrary length, he wants to replace that entire word with stars. ```Test``` was just an example of a string with 4 letters in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an arbitrary text to be replaced, and you want to use `replaceAll()`, be aware that it takes a regular expression, and various characters have special meaning. To prevent issues, call `Pattern.quote()`.

Also, to replace with a sequence of `*` of equal length, you need to build a string of such.

Here is a nice short method for doing it:

```
private static String mask(String input, String codeword) {
    char[] buf = new char[codeword.length()];
    Arrays.fill(buf, '*');
    return input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(codeword), new String(buf));
}
```

**Test**

```
System.out.println(mask("_test_", "test"));
System.out.println(mask("This is his last chance", "is"));
```

**Output**

```
_****_
Th** ** h** last chance
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are ***pretty close*** the what you want. This is what you can do:

```
System.out.println("_test_".replaceAll("[test]", "*"));
System.out.println("hello".replaceAll("[el]", "*"));
```

**Output:**

```
_****_
h***o
```

Comment: Not good, since `"hello".replaceAll("[test]", "*")` would produce `h*llo`, replacing the `e` even though the string doesn't contain `test`.

Comment: @Andreas OP didn't say he wants the entire text sequence which match to be replaced.